# Multiple versions of html2canvas

Tags: javascript, npm, html2canvas

I updated version of html2canvas from v0.5.0 to v1.0.0, then a certain function stopped working on iOS.

So, I'd like to use v0.5.0 on iOS and v1.0.0 on other devices.

How can I have and use both versions of html2canvas on my web app?

Comment: If it is in the same page, it might be difficult to use different versions with two script tags. For jQuery we have jQuery's noconflict mode. http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing custom function.

```
 (function (w, d) {
        "use strict";
        var h = d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
            s = d.createElement("script");
        w.d3 = null;
        s.src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0/html2canvas.min.js";
        s.onload = function () {
            w.d3_3_5_3 = w.d3;
            w.d3 = undefined;
            s = d.createElement("script");
            s.src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0/html2canvas.min.js";
            s.onload = function () {
                w.d3_3_5_4 = w.d3;
                w.d3 = undefined;
                s = d.createElement("script");
                s.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.0.0/html2canvas.min.js";
                s.onload = function () {
                    w.d3_3_5_5 = w.d3;
                    w.d3 = undefined;
                };
                h.appendChild(s);
            };
            h.appendChild(s);
        };
        h.appendChild(s);
    }(window, document));
```

Hope this helps.!

Comment: The above code seems to be for d3. I should apply it to "w.html2canvas" instead of "W.d3", is it right?

Comment: Give it a try. See what is the function output. d3 is just a variable. Never mind. Feel free to refactor.